# "Unreachable code detected"

Tags: c#-4.0

```
static int Simple() {
    for (int v = 211; v < 661; v++) {
            return v;
    }
}
```

The 'v' in v++ is underlined and my debugger says unreachable code detected.

Comment: Why would you have code like that? It's simply returning 211. Often unreachable code means you have a logic error in your code.

Comment: I accidentally oversimplified my question by errantly knocking out an if conditional that's critical to the logic.

Comment: And I'm still learning C variant syntax (was unfamiliar until just today with the full implications of 'return').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will turn your loop into something like:

```
int v = 211;

loop:
if (v < 661)
{
    return v;
} else {
    v++;
    goto loop;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because it will never reach that portion of the code. It will return on first iteration of the `for` loop. Remember, this is the order of execution of a for loop in C#:

```
for (init; condition; increment) {
    body;
}
```

1. init
2. condition
3. body (if condition is true)
4. increment

Comment: I wish I could green check all of the posters who answered this.

Answer (score 4):

The return statement is going to exit the loop immediately, and the v++ won't get a chance to execute.

Comment: I think you mean "exit" as opposed to "execute"?

Answer (score 2):

It will never get to do the increment because you are returning the value of `v` after the first step through the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

you are defining a for loop which iterates over 450 values, but you are returning in the first iteration of the loop (which leaves the function body and therefore stops the execution of the for loop!). Over the other 449 values won't be iterated, so that code is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

Because `v` is incremented after the execution of the loop's body. But that tells "hey, don't loop again, go away!", so `v` will never be incremented.